# Remove auto added "http://" in wordpress user website

Tags: wordpress

When I add a website (url) to a user in wordpress, it automatically gets "http://" added to the start of the url. Is there a way to stop this happening? It is causing other plugins to not function properly as I call on the user_url but need the http to not be present?
edit: i have tried editing user-edit.php to change the "Website:" field input type to text instead of url, but no avail.
Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What plugins are causing issues with that? It usually works perfect and must not have any issues as per my opinion.

but there is one trick that MIGHT work in this scenario : using [Protocol relative URLs](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

So instead of putting user website as "www.yahoo.com", try putting "**//www.yahoo.com**" and see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Ash
I use Ninja Forms and a field is auto-populated with wp:user_url except I need it to not add the "http://", which is being added automatically when I have any value in the "website" (url) field on the user page. I have tried text, numbers, url but it all seems to get the "http://" added to it..

Comment: ah I see. The code would be checking the protocol being absent and add a default HTTP in that case. Try adding "//" before the website and it should work.